# Cannot convert source type T? to target type T?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics

I want to create simple cache manager (for Redis) who return value genereic type **T** but when i deserialize value from Redis i got error `cannot convert source type T? to target type T?`

```
public class InMemoryCacheService<T> : ICacheService<T>
{
   private T? cacheValue = default(T?);

   public async Task<T> GetValueAsync<T>(string key, Expression<T> expression)
   {
       
      GetCacheGalueAsync<T>(key);

      //code where I check if cacheValue is null get value from DB
   }


   public void GetCacheGalueAsync<T>(string key) 
   {
      string value = _distributedCache.GetString(key);
      if (value is not null)
      {
         T? t = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);

         //cannot convert source type T? to target type T?
         cacheValue = t;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of defining a generic argument on the method when you also define the generic argument on the class with the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different type parameters called `T` here. One is in the generic *type* declaration:

```cs
public class InMemoryCacheService<T>
```

The other is in the generic *method* declaration:

```cs
public void GetCacheGalueAsync<T>(string key)
```

If you rename these respectively to `TClass` and `TMethod`, you'll see a different error message, converting `TMethod?` to `TClass?`.

I strongly suspect you just want to make your method non-generic:

```cs
public void GetCacheValueAsync(string key)
```

That way `T` will just refer to the type parameter declared by the class.